# Is there a good Fogbugz client for Windows

Tags: windows, fogbugz

Funnily enough, I already found some pointers and a thread to an OSX client for Fogbugz. Here
I am looking for a Windows client.

I know there are web browsers for Windows, but I am looking for fast editing; fast changing of attributes ("one click"); zapping through cases and edits in milliseconds; no waiting for HTTP round trips, just pure speed.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

Not that we're aware of. Sorry.

Anyone looking to develop something like this, though, should [contact us at Fog Creek](http://contact.fogcreek.com/).

We can certainly help you with any questions.